# How to check if webkitdirectory works using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, input, directory

In my web app, I am using folder select on an input field. This is the feature

https://caniuse.com/#search=webkitdirectory

However, I am also doing some compatibility checking to make sure the feature exists before the user tries to use it. Is there a way I can quickly check in javascript to see if this feature exists?

I am looking for something similarly for if I want to check if webworkers exist, I can do `if (window.Worker) {}`

Does anyone know?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In supported browsers, an `HTMLInputElement` will have the property `webkitdirectory` set to `true` or `false`.

We can use this fact to check compatibility:

```
var input = document.createElement("input");

if(typeof input.webkitdirectory !== "boolean") {
    // not supported
}
```